# How would one subtract a millisecond from a \DateTime?

Tags: php

For a given code

```
$now = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
// $oneMsAgo = ???

var_dump($now->format(\DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED));
```

what would be a **reliable** way to subtract one millisecond to get another `\DateTime` object?

By "reliable" I mean - it should be a valid date time that respects all time zone nuances and DST, as if you were subtracting a second with `\DateInterval('PT1S')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question

```
$oneMsAgo = (clone $now)->setTime($now->format('H'), $now->format('i'), $now->format('s'), $now->format('u') - 1000);
```